# stopping page reload when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, reload

I am trying to reload a page with a button in it. When the user click on the button an alert window should popup and the page reload should stop until ok is clicked on the alert window.

I am writing my code as follows:

```
<button id="myButton" onclick="myfunction()"> Test </button>

<script type="text/javascript">

 function myfunction()
  {
    if ( document.getElementById("myButton").onclick == false )
     {
        window.setTimeout(function(){ document.location.reload(true); }, 1000);
     }
    else
    {
       alert ( "Timer Not Set." );
    }
  }
</script>
```

Neither the if or else conditions are working.

Comment: Just use a `confirm` instead of `alert`?

Comment: @abhitalks its not working.

Comment: `if (confirm("reload?")) { document.location.reload(true); }`

Comment: @abhitalks initially i want the page to get reloaded for every 2mins. When the user clicks on the button an alert pops up and page reload should halt until the alert window is closed.

Comment: Ah.. do you mean this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/79v0xfjd/1/ ?

Comment: @abhitalks thanks that solved the issue. Been trying to solve the issue since few days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use setInterval and then clearInterval whenever you want to pause or stop, and then reassign setInterval to resume.

Something on the lines of this:

```
var timer = window.setInterval(reloader, 3000);

$("#btn").on("click", function() {
    clearInterval(timer);
    alert("Just click ok");
    timer = window.setInterval(reloader, 3000);
});

function reloader() {
    document.location.reload(true);
}
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/79v0xfjd/1/

.

Comment: do you have any idea about Oracle Apex? If so kindly message me as i have some issue regarding the above code when inserting it there.

Comment: Sorry. No idea about that buddy. :(